# How secure it is to identify a user by an sms's caller id?

Tags: sms

I need to verify a user based on its phone number. I am thinking that instead of me sending him an sms, it would be cheaper if he sends me the sms and I verify he's phone number based on his caller ID. Is it trustable? Or can it be faked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be faked.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_spoofing

If you want to validate a phone, you should make sure they get what you send rather than trusting they are who they say they are.